# What could cause Mozart to be a common name?

Tags: humanoid, names, music

My Keplerians, a humanoid race that looks similar to humans on the outside but is not human, have a futuristic civilization on 1 planet and a stone age civilization on a similar planet. The futuristic civilization is what I am talking about in this question.

Musicians often start as children. In fact, finding a musician that did not start as a child is rare. But there is usually 1 child in the city who was able to read music before he/she could read words and who started on an instrument, typically the Keplerian equivalent of a violin, very early on. This child typically started composing not long after the child started playing an instrument. Reminds me of a certain composer. That composer is [Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfgang_Amadeus_Mozart). But there is no way that Keplerians would know about this composer.

That 1 child in the city is known as "Mozart of the city". Some actually decide to change their last name to Mozart but that takes 10 years to become official. There is a special maglev system for Keplerian composers, most of whom have Mozart in their name, either officially or colloquially. But if not from knowledge of Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart, what would cause Mozart to be as common of a name as it is for Keplerian musicians?

Comment: names are just conventional labels. I am afraid this cannot be other than an opinion based question

Comment: You mean a name *pronounced* `/ˈmoʊtsɑːrt/`? Or maybe `/ˈmoːtsaʁt/`? Or maybe a name which *means* "bogman" or "marshman" in their language?

Comment: Assuming that they magically speak a language bearing and incredibly coincidental similarity to English:  Over centuries, the title of "The Most Artful Composer" becomes corrupted to  "The Mos-Artf Composer", and finally "The Mozart Composer"

Answer (score 2):

Convergence and coincidence. if the Keplerians are humanoids then there is the distinct possibility that their languages may use similar phonetic and sound systems to human languages. This will include words that might homophones of existing Earth human words. Due to a convergence in language and nomenclature the Keplerians happened to produce a musical genius whose name was a homophone of the name of "Mozart". Other Keplerian musical geniuses received recognition as being other "Mozarts".

Once established, it could readily follow other persons adopted the name of Mozart or changed their names to it. This could be simply a matter of conforming to Keplerian cultural practice. Essentially being called or named Mozart is a badge or symbol of recognition of being a musician among Keplerians.

The fact that this name resembles or is in any way similar to that our Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart is only a matter of the purest coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

Well while they perhaps don't consciously know about Mozart, they may have somehow subconsciously picked up "memetic echos" of the former from across the galaxy through some hidden telepathic potential that your species has.

Imagine it, Mozart's legacy somehow expanding past the Earth and into the larger universe by sheer virtue of its majesty and impact. In what form, I don't know. Psychic energy? Memetic information? But in one way or another those reality warping waves eventually reach the planet of your Keplerians and inspires them deep down to recognize the term "Mozart" as in some way significant when it comes to music.

In fact given this idea it could be that even some of the words we Earthlings have were originally inspired by the names of alien greats long dead.

Perhaps Genius was the name of an alien savant a thousand light years from here who cracked the deepest mysteries of the cosmos.
Maybe Virtuoso was an incredible artist in the Andromeda galaxy who painted a canvas that could make anyone weep.

Is this fanciful? Yes, very. But so was your question.